# Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python (With Greater and less than)

Tags: python

Is there was a way I could do a rock paper scissors game with greater than and less than signs?

I know there are different ways of doing RPS, but I want to know specifically about greater and less than.

Here is my code:

```
"Rock" > "Scissors" and 'Rock' < 'Paper'
"Paper" > "Rock" and 'Scissors' < 'Rock' 
"Sissors" > "Paper" and 'Paper' < 'Scissors'
choose1 = input("Player One, Enter your answer ")
choose2 = input("Player Two, Enter your answer ")

if choose1 == "Paper":
    "Paper" > "Rock"
if choose1 == "Scissor":
    "Scissor" > "Rock"


if choose1 != "Rock" and choose1 != "Paper" and choose1 != "Scissors":
    print("Player one please chose Rock, Paper, or Scissors")

if choose2 != "Rock" and choose2 != "Paper" and choose2 != "Scissors":
    print("Player two please chose Rock, Paper, or Scissors")

if choose1 > choose2:
    print('Player1 ({}) beats ({})'.format (choose1, choose2))
else:
    print('Player2 ({}) beats ({})'.format (choose2, choose1))
```

The game works, however, it sees rock as beating everything, paper beating only scissors, and  scissors beating nothing.

How do I fix this code so it performs correctly?

Comment: What do you think the line at the top are doing? (Spoiler, they're doing nothing)

Comment: the problem is that the order is cyclic: P > R > S, but S > P. so the > will not be transitive... you could always create a class and hack [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to do what you want.

Comment: like `"Rock"` is string. So neither `>` nor `<` wouldn't do any thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use `<` and `>`, make classes, simple string will not comply your needs.

```
class Rock:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Scissors)

class Paper:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Rock)

class Scissors:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Paper)


CHOICES = {
    "rock": Rock(),
    "paper": Paper(),
    "scissors": Scissors()
}

a = CHOICES["rock"]
b = CHOICES["scissors"]

print("player a wins:", a > b)
```

**EDIT**: or maybe better with only one class

```
class RPS:
    table = {
        "rock": "scissors",
        "paper": "rock",
        "scissors": "paper"
    }

    def __init__(self, what):
        self.what = what
        self.winsover = self.table[what]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.what == other.what

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.winsover == other.what


a = RPS("rock")
b = RPS("scissors")

print("player a wins:", a > b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of choices, each k/v pair represents the *choice*, and the item which that choice will "beat" in the RPS game, then you can test the two players' choices like so:

```
def rps():
    """
        choices defines the choice, and opposing choice which it will beat
    """
    choices = {'rock':'scissors', 'paper':'rock', 'scissors':'paper'}

    c1 = raw_input("Player One, Enter your answer ")
    c2 = raw_input("Player Two, Enter your answer ")

    if choices[c1] == c2:
        print 'player 1 wins, {} beats {}'.format(c1,c2)
    elif choices[c2] == c1:
        print 'player 2 wins, {} beats {}'.format(c2,c1)
    else:
        print 'both players choose {}'.format(c1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure "mathematical" form using the operators lt and gt, without hacking the operators can be achieved.

```
#ask the choices and map to P=3,R=2,S=1, using a dictionary for instance
#any difference between options will work as long as simmetric 
#and the rest is adapted with the step different from one

result = abs(choose1 - choose2)
if not result:
    print "Tie"

if result == 1:
    #choose max
    if choose1 > choose2:
         print "Player 1 wins"
    else:
         print "Player 2 wins"
else: 
    #choose min:
    if choose1 < choose2:
         print "Player 1 wins"
    else:
         print "Player 2 wins"
```

Comment: Good stuff! That is what I was going for before I just went the "easy" route with my dict appraoch.  This one is neat, and meets OP requirements to use the GT/LT operators.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this was some homework and not pure curiosity, but still an interesting problem. I stuck to the OP request, however the hacks have more upvotes :/ I do like your answer though